# Maximum QTY allowed in shopping cart error

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, bug

When I set a product to have a maximum allowed in cart to 10 and test on the website the cart won't allow more than 10. But if I add more than 10 - say 30 you cannot checkout but the individual price and total price shows a reduction.

**Example product priced at 15.99 when you add 30 the price shows as 1.24 each.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @RolandW You might have set other configurations like shopping cart price rules or coupons.

Comment: Hi Gideon, there are no coupons or shopping cart price rules set up for this product.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a Tier Price. There is a section in Price from which you can set the Tier Price. Thats give the facility to reduce the price for bulk purchase.

Remove all the Tier Price option and try again.

Comment: Hi, i do not have any tier prices set up for this product. Thanks

Comment: @RolandW, check it on store level